# The mistake in opening a json-file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Good evening! I'm learning angular.js and at the moment I'm trying to get access to the json-file to load some data from the server, but, ubfortunately, $http - method gives an error. Please? help me to find a mistake.

A code of the controller that sends a query:

```
(function(){
var app =angular.module('SCBI', []) ;
app.controller('TeachersController', function TeachersController ($scope, $http){

$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://patutinskiy.esy.es/javascripts/json/all_teachers.json'}).
         success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.teachers=data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(status);

});
});
})();
```

Json-file is OK (checked in the parser). Thank you!

Comment: How about your error?

Comment: hmm..the page just does not load. If I try alert(status) it prints 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the http://patutinskiy.esy.es/ server doesn't allow cross origin request. If you enable javascript debug when running above script it will throw following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://patutinskiy.esy.es/javascripts/json/all_teachers.json. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin    
'xxx' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If you have the access of mentioned server then you have to add header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Read these for more detail:

- [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Send header before encode json.

```
"Content-type: application/json"
```

And how u encode to json?

Comment: Aaa, can you please type the code? I'm afraid, I don't undestant what you mean(

Comment: The file is already in json (on the server). Why should I encode it?